# Sphere to sphere collision (C++)

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-engine, physics

I am implementing some basic 3D physics engine. For sphere to sphere collision I am following this [tutorial](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php?page=2). I have problems with with 2 moving spheres. I guess there maybe some problem with the way I am finding "shortened velocity"

```
bool collidingDSmove(Sphere sphere){
    // Early Escape test: if the length of the movevec is less
    // than distance between the centers of these circles minus 
    // their radii, there's no way they can hit.
```

In my test scene velocity vectors are (-2,-4,-2) and (1,2,1). Therefore "shortVel" becomes actually greater than the original velocities.

```
    vec3 shortVel = sphere.velocity.substract(velocity);
    vec3 fromAtoBCenter = position.substract(sphere.position);
    float distSquare = fromAtoBCenter.getLengthSquare();
    float sumRadii = (radius + sphere.radius);
    distSquare -= sumRadii*sumRadii;
    if (shortVel.getLengthSquare() < distSquare){
        return false;
    }

    // Normalize the movevec
    vec3 N = shortVel.normalize();

    // Find C, the vector from the center of the moving 
    // circle A to the center of B
    vec3 C = sphere.position.substract(position);

    // D = N . C = ||C|| * cos(angle between N and C)
    float D = N.dot(C);

    // Another early escape: Make sure that A is moving 
    // towards B! If the dot product between the movevec and 
    // B.center - A.center is less that or equal to 0, 
    // A isn't isn't moving towards B
    if (D <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    // Find the length of the vector C
    float lengthCSquare = C.getLengthSquare();

    float F = (lengthCSquare)-(D * D);

    // Escape test: if the closest that A will get to B 
    // is more than the sum of their radii, there's no 
    // way they are going collide
    float sumRadiiSquared = sumRadii * sumRadii;
    if (F >= sumRadiiSquared){
        return false;
    }

    // We now have F and sumRadii, two sides of a right triangle. 
    // Use these to find the third side, sqrt(T)
    double T = sumRadiiSquared - F;

    // If there is no such right triangle with sides length of 
    // sumRadii and sqrt(f), T will probably be less than 0. 
    // Better to check now than perform a square root of a 
    // negative number. 
    if (T < 0){
        return false;
    }

    // Therefore the distance the circle has to travel along 
    // movevec is D - sqrt(T)
    float distance = D - sqrt(T);

    // Get the magnitude of the movement vector
    float mag = velocity.getLength();

    // Finally, make sure that the distance A has to move 
    // to touch B is not greater than the magnitude of the 
    // movement vector. 
    if (mag < distance){
        return false;
    }
```

//*** amount is not between 0 and 1

```
    float amount = shortVel.normalize().getLength() / velocity.getLength();
    // Set the length of the movevec so that the circles will just 
    // touch
    velocity = velocity.normalize().times(amount);
    sphere.velocity = sphere.velocity.normalize().times(amount);

    return true;
}
```

My vec3 class is as following:

```
class vec3 {
public:
    float x; float y; float z;
    vec3() : x(0), y(0), z(0) { }
    vec3 substract(vec3 v){
        vec3 sub;
        sub.x = x - v.x;
        sub.y = y - v.y;
        sub.z = z - v.z;
        return sub;
    }
float getLength() {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
float getLengthSquare() {
        return x*x + y*y + z*z;
    }
vec3 normalize(){
        vec3 n;
        n.x = x / getLength();
        n.y = y / getLength();
        n.z = z / getLength();
        return n;
    }
float dot(vec3 v) {
        return x*v.x + y*v.y + z*v.z;
    }
}
```

Could you please explain me what im doing wrong here?

**Here is my Update function. Where deltaT is time lapsed between 2 frames**

```
void updateVelocity(double deltaT){
        velocity.x = velocity.x + acceleration.x*deltaT;
        velocity.y = velocity.y + acceleration.y*deltaT;
        velocity.z = velocity.z + acceleration.z*deltaT;
    }
    void updatePosition(double deltaT){
        position.x = position.x + velocity.x * deltaT + 0.5 * acceleration.x * deltaT * deltaT;
        position.y = position.y + velocity.y * deltaT + 0.5 * acceleration.y * deltaT * deltaT;
        position.z = position.z + velocity.z * deltaT + 0.5 * acceleration.z * deltaT * deltaT;
    }
    void update(double deltaT){
        updateVelocity(deltaT);
        updatePosition(deltaT);

    }
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but shouldn't `shortVel.normalize().getLength() ` be `1`? I mean, the length of a normalized vector is always `1`, right?

Comment: That's true. I have added this normalize() step in attempt to fix the code. Author of tutorial does not mention normalization step. Quoting: If they collide, divide the length of the shortened vector by the length of the one you originally passed into the function. The result should be a floating-point number between 0 and 1. This represents when over the course of their movement the circles collided. Multiply the original movement vectors by this number

Comment: One thing you did is to neglect proper maintenance of projects on this scale. You should know, that either `vec3` is at fault or skip it at all. Particularly, you didn't write unit tests for the modules that are complete. Also, why don't you take a pencil and an envelope and check your algorithm step-by-step see if everything behaves like it should? This question is unfortunately also out of topic, because you ask about what is wrong with the code with out a minimal example, nor any expected input and output.

Comment: what are the problems you have?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "movement vector" in the article is the object's movement in this frame, i.e. velocity multiplied by timestep, *not* the velocity (unless you're measuring speed in distance per frame, in which case you should stop doing that immedately.)

Comment: Pen and pencil was used to test the tutorial algorithm. It helped me to find out that the problem is in amount. for the first collision occurrence the "amout" variable is 3.

Comment: @molbdnilo Hmmm... I am not quite sure what u mean. I will now add my update function code

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what is the intention of shortVel ? The articule uses the difference in distance but not in velocities.

Comment: Author of the article did not put the whole code there. He describes "shortVel" in the third paragraph under the title Bank Shot: Collision between two moving circles

Comment: So the line float amount = shortVel.getLength() / velocity.getLength(); (without normalizing shortVel) is giving you values >1 ? Is the update sequential or you are using multithreads or other form of parallelism?

Comment: @Inventor The author consistently uses the term "movement vector". This is not the velocity. It is the "path" that an object would travel in the timestep if it didn't collide with anything.

Comment: @molbdnilo I see. So the movement vector would be velocity.normilize().times(deltaT) ?

Answer (score 3):

First, create add and times functions in vec3.

If a sphere s1 and a sphere s2, with a position p (vec3), velocity v (vec3), radius r (float) and mass m (float) collides, you can do:

```
// from s1 to s2
vec3 pDiff = s2.p.subtract(s1.p);
// collision detection
if (pDiff.getLength() >= s1.r + s2.r) {
    return;
}
// find direction from s1 to s2
vec3 dir = pDiff.normalize();
vec3 vDiff = s2.v.subtract(s1.v);
float fellingSpeed = vDiff.dot(dir);
// don't collide in this case
if (fellingSpeed >= 0) {
    return;
}
// perfect spheric collision
float speed1 = (2 * s2.m * fellingSpeed) / (s1.m + s2.m);
float speed2 = (fellingSpeed * (s2.m - s1.m)) / (s1.m + s2.m);
s1.v = s1.v.add(dir.times(speed1));
s2.v = s2.v.add(dir.times(speed2 - fellingSpeed));
```

I hope it helps.